# Confusion about triangle formation.

Tags: probability, puzzle

A stick of unit length is cut in three parts. Whats the probability that it'll form a triangle.  The condition which i used $x_2+x_2\geq x_3$ where they denote sides but i get probability as $\infty$ as $x_3$ can be infinitely small maybe $dx$ and the other two are much larger. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The probability depends on how we choose the two places where we cut the stick. Is anything else said about how the stick is cut? Did you know that if you hold a strand of uncooked spaghetti at both ends and bend it, it will break in three pieces, not two? The way it breaks seems random but does not have the same distribution as people usually mean when they pose questions like yours.

Answer (score 2):

You need to impose all three constraints:  $x_1+x_2\gt x_3, x_2+x_3\gt x_1,x_3+x_1\gt x_2$. In your example if $x_3$ is very small, the first will be easy to satisfy, but the other two will not.  Alternately, you can sort them so that $x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3$ and then just require $x_1+x_2 \gt x_3$ as the other two are satisfied automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Make two cuts (I assume you mean) uniformly along the unit length. Call the smaller $x$ and the larger $y$. Then there are three spacings: $x$, $y-x$, and $1-y$. Then under the conditions of the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) $(\star)$, the probability of forming a triangle is 
\begin{align*}
P(\triangle) &= P(x+(y-x)>1-y\cup x+(1-y)>y-x \cup (y-x)+(1-y)>x)\tag{$\star$}\\
&= P(y>1-y\cup 2x+1 >2y\cup 1-x>x)\\
&=P\left(y>\frac{1}{2}\cup x+\frac{1}{2}>y \cup \frac{1}{2}>x\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\\&=\frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get $P\left(y>\frac{1}{2}\cup x+\frac{1}{2}>y \cup \frac{1}{2}>x\right) = \frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\\=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Lucifer- I can't remember exactly at the moment, but I'm pretty sure I used inclusion-exclusion. Also, I probably drew a picture for myself. If you need more help, just ask again.

Comment: I know inclusion-exclusion and tried doing as you said but can't figure it out. Can you elaborate a bit more on the topic. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucifer- I thought about it some more and I realized I might have made a mistake. I know the answer is $1/4$, but my work is incorrect. Let me know when you read this so I can delete this answer. If I figure out how to fix it, I will let you know.

Comment: Okay. I will also try looking for a solution, meanwhile. I would let you know if I come up with a solution( though I highly doubt I can solve this problem)

Answer (score 0):

Don't get too worried about the infinities.  Let's wave these away by saying that if $x_1 + x_2 = x_3$ we have a triangle.

Let's say that the first cut produces $x_1$ and $x_2 + x_3$.  We then cut the second piece to produce $x_2$ and $x_3$.  Let's say that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1.$

If $x_1 > 1/2$ then we won't get a triangle.  If it's not, then we may.

Let's say that $x_1 = (1/2) - y$, where $0 < y \leq 1/2.$  Then, we'll get a triangle only when $x_2 > y$ OR $x_3 > y$.

So the probability of getting a triangle, given that $0 \leq y \leq 1/2$ is

$$P(y) = \frac{(1/2)+y-2y}{(1/2) + y} = \frac{1 - 2y}{1+2y}.$$

Then we can integrate the region from $0$ to $1/2$, and take the region from $1/2$ to $1$ to be zero to get the answer:

$$P(y) = \int_0^{1/2}\frac{(1-2y)dy}{1+2y} = \ln 2 - (1/2) \approx 0.193.$$